# Return two dimensional array of integer and boolean

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that stores `team_id` (INT) `player_id` (INT) and `active` (BOOLEAN) for a team.

Currently, there is a data structure that returns a JSON with team details and one of the keys is "players" which is an array of integers, that looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "team_id": 1,
  "team_name": "Team Name",
  "players": [
    2,
    23,
    44,
    45
  ],
 }
]
```

For each player, i would also like to return the BOOLEAN of `active` column, so the structure would look like this:

```
[
 {
  "team_id": 1,
  "team_name": "Team Name",
  "players": [
    [2, TRUE]
    [23, TRUE]
    [44, FALSE]
    [45, TRUE]
  ],
 }
]
```

To generate data for "players" key, the sql is as follows:

```
SELECT team_vs_players.team_id,
   ARRAY_AGG(team_vs_players.player_id) AS players
FROM team.team_vs_players
GROUP BY team_vs_players.team_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix an `int` with a `boolean` in a native PostgreSQL array.

To combine these values, you will need to create a `jsonb` array.

If this does not work directly because of implicit casts, then we may need to see your final step that produces the output json.

```
SELECT team_vs_players.team_id,
   ARRAY_AGG(jsonb_build_array(team_vs_players.player_id, team_vs_players.active)) AS players
FROM team.team_vs_players
GROUP BY team_vs_players.team_id
```